# How to verify the page title, subtitle, graph, chart data by using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on **Selenium WebDriver** and code I'm writing in **Java**.

My scenario is to compare the Page Title,Sub tilte, Graph, Chart Data are matching with the FE.

The `Page Title,Sub tilte, Graph, Chart Data` I need to store in Property file then i need to compare with the FE.

The Page title looks like this:

[image]
The HTML as follows:

```
<h2>
New PR's
<p>Month Wise Overall New PR's </p>
</h2>
```

The chart data Looks like this:
[image]

HTML:

```
div class="drilDownTabularDataWrapper">
<h3>Month Wise Overall New PR's - Jan 2014 To Jun 2014 - Chart Data</h3>
<table class="drilDownTabularData" width="950">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: I"m the beginner could you please give me some ideas

Comment: Pretty much everything you're wanting to do is detailed in the `Webdriver` documentation. I'll provide you with how to get the page title and a link to the getting started guide. `String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();` https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: WebElement pt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/h1/span"));
 System.out.println(" " + pt);

Comment: i tried with the above line but the problem I'm getting a different output **[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (297e4973-5abb-49a0-9414-23c52c768260)] -> xpath: /html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/h1/span]**. Actually it need to compare the **New PR's** in the above image